# TableView Extension indexPathsFor `Un` SelectedRows

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Everybody knows about the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` - but here come the time that i need to know the rows that are not selected

I would like to make an extension of it.

Is there any chance somebody already have done it or have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do?  I would probably load the selected rows in an NSIndexSet and then use `contains` on your row to determine if it is selected or not

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one section in the table view you could simply

- Map all row indexes from `indexPathsForSelectedRows`to an `Int` array.

  ```
  let rowIndexes = indexPathsForSelectedRows.map { $0.row }
  ```
- Create an `Int` array from the indexes in the `dataSourceArray`

  ```
  let allIndexes = 0..<dataSourceArray.count
  ```
- Filter the indexes which are not in `allIndexes` and create new index paths

  ```
  let indexPathsForDeselectedRows = allIndexes.filter {!rowIndexes.contains($0) }.map {NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0)}
  ```

If there are multiple sections it's a bit more complex.

Comment: this worked for my case, i was also headed this way, but i wanted to make a more generic function/extension of the UITableView itself